# ubuntu Terminal takes too long to load - only first time

Tags: 16.04

Ubuntu terminal takes atleast 50 seconds to show up the username .i mean it application opens immediately but to show up the username@host it takes long time. i thought i polluted ~/.bashrc,but even after commenting out all the extra path i added ,it is still slow

Comment: I thought ~/.bashrc is not the only file that is executed when a terminal is started. Do you recollect making changes to for example /etc/profile or others? Perhaps an idea to add the contents of ~/.bashrc to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to the top of `.bashrc` and `.profile`:

```
set -x
```

and `set +x` at the bottom of those two files

Edit: I should've added an explanation of what these two commands do.
Bit late, but [here they are](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36273740/7642528).

Comment: Alright,that helped to debug...actually i installed NVM which causes the delay...Thank you!